# How to create an automated range for dummy in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dummy-variable, dummy-data

I have the followinf DF and  I want to create a dummy with automated scale to represent categorically whether a city has little, medium, or a lot of companies.

| cities | sum of companies |
| --- | --- |
| CTY A | 199 |
| CITY B | 358 |
| CITY C | 250 |
| CITY D | 1265 |
| CITY E | 610 |

I tried the following code:

```
#install.packages("scales")
library(scales)

    COMP_SCALES<- breaks_extended() #from packages Scales
    COMP_A<-COMP_SCALES(df[2], n =4)
    COMP_A <- cut(df[2], 
                          breaks=c(-Inf, COMP_A[2],COMP_A[3],COMP_A[4], Inf), 
                          labels=c("LITTLE","MEDIUM","A LOT OF","+ A LOT OF"))
```

However, the automatic calculated scale is not very suitable, once all the cities are on little range. How can I better automate this code?

The final porpuse is to create a table to better visualize the result with something like this:

```
COMP_A_CLUSTER <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(COMP_A,kmeans.k$cluster))
```

Expected outcome:
City A Should be placed on the "**Little**".
City B and C Should be placed on the "**Medium**".
City E Should be placed on the "**a lot of**".
City D should be placed on the "**+ a lot of**".

I have a list of more than 10,000 cities and more than 100 columns to do such a similar process and that is why I wanted the scale of the dummies to be calculated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own functions if you know what are the end (right) boundaries of each of the categories. Below is a simple example. DF has a new column 'CatCities' and has what you are seeking.

Following assumptions are there

- The lowest value, for sum.of.companies, is greater than or equal to 0
- The highest value, for sum.of.companies, is 10000 (You can change it)
- 'CategoryList' in the function argument is strictly increasing (from lowest to highest) and so is the argument 'EndPoints'
- The length of the vectors for the arguments, 'CategoryList' and 'EndPoints', are equal in the function call

```
DF <- read.csv("./SomeDF.csv")
ClassifyRange <- function(x, CategoryList=c("Little","Medium","a lof of","+a lot of"),EndPoints=c(250,500,1000,10000)){
  Index <- which((EndPoints -x) >= 0)
  return(CategoryList[Index[1]])
}

DF$CatCities <- lapply(DF$sum.of.companies, FUN=ClassifyRange)
```

It produces the following output

[image: Output of the function. The right most column is the category of the cities]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quantile` to pick intervals with equal numbers of samples in each. By default, `quantile` breaks into 4 intervals (`probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25)`), but you can specify different intervals to the `probs` argument.

```
 COMP_A <- cut(df[,2], 
               breaks=quantile(df[,2]), 
               labels=c("LITTLE","MEDIUM","A LOT OF","+ A LOT OF"))
```